# Bat properly grounded or not behind the popping creass

Tags: cricket

If W/K gloves lies on the ground behind the popping crease and batter put his bat on it, whether it is properly grounded or not?
Please find the attached image for your reference.[image: Bat grounded or not?]

Comment: How did the glove get there in the first place?